# DRF response body for generic viewsets: How are the errors structured?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have some generic APIs on DRF, like below:

```
class CustomUserViewset(AutoPermissionViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.none()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        current_user = self.request.user
        if current_user.is_superuser:
            # Superuser can see everyone
            return User.objects.all()
        # If you are not a superuser, You can only see yourself
        return User.objects.filter(pk=current_user.pk)

    def get_object(self):
        if self.kwargs["pk"] == "me":
            # Make it so that calling /accounts/api/users/me return info about current user
            self.kwargs["pk"] = self.request.user.pk
        if self.kwargs["pk"] is None:
            return User(is_active=None)
        return super().get_object()
```

Now, imagine I want to handle catching error messages and showing them to users in the front-end part. I need to know in what structure the errors are being shown, and with what key should I retrieve it. I'm 99% sure that there is a standard structure that DRF uses for response bodies when errors occurs, but I could not find anything with a quick search. I also couldn't find any related questions regarding this in stackoverflow, so, if this question is duplicate, please comment the question.

Another viewset that I need to know the structure of the response in case of errors:

```
class OCRDocumentViewset(AutoPermissionViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.OCRDocument.objects.all()
    pagination_class = None

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"request": None})
        return context

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.kwargs.get("pk"):
            return serializers.OCRDocumentDetailSerializer
        return serializers.OCRDocumentSerializer
```

Comment: it is EXCEPTION_HANDLER. Use this link for more detail https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a key based error handler in the front-end. So, in the redux store, I added a `error` key with the type of `string | { [key: string]: string } | null`. `string` for the errors that will be produced manually, and the `dict` for the errors that will be sent by the API response. For example:

```
export interface TranscriptionStoreType {
    loading: boolean
    error: string | { [key: string]: string } | null
    transcriptions: TranscriptionType[]
    reviewResponse: ReviewResponseType
    currentLineIndex: number
}
```

Then, in the reducers, I get the response object and save it in the `error` key:

```
.addCase(PAGE_REVIEW_ACTIONS.GET_TRANSCRIPTIONS_ERROR, (state = initialState, action: ReduxActionData<any>) => {
            state.error = action.payload.response.data
            state.loading = false
        })
```

After that, I created an `ErrorHandling` component, which will receive the `error` from the state, and depending on the type of the error, will handle displaying it. this is the component:

```
import React from 'react'

interface ErrorHandlingProps {
    error: string | { [key: string]: string }
}

const ErrorHandling: React.FC<ErrorHandlingProps> = ({ error }) => {
    let errorString: (string | JSX.Element)[]

    if (typeof error === 'string') {
        // If error is already a string, use it directly
        errorString = error.split('<br />').map((line, index) => (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
                {line}
                <br />
            </React.Fragment>
        ))
    } else if (typeof error === 'object') {
        // Check for common error keys, this list will be extended based on the needs
        const commonErrorKeys = ['detail', 'message', 'error']
        const foundKey = commonErrorKeys.find((key) => key in error)

        if (foundKey) {
            // If a common error key is found, use its value
            errorString = [error[foundKey]] // Wrap it in an array
        } else {
            // If no common key is found, stringify the entire object
            errorString = [JSON.stringify(error)] // Wrap it in an array
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback for unknown types
        errorString = ['An unknown error occurred'] // Wrap it in an array
    }

    return <div className="m-3 alert alert-warning col-12">{errorString}</div>
}

export default ErrorHandling
```

Now, wherever I come across an error, I will call this component with the `error`:

```
{error && <ErrorHandling error={error} />}
```

For now, it works perfectly. In the future, as I encounter new errors, I will just add the new key inside the `ErrorHandling` component.